# How to enable phone auth firebase, flutter, xcode

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter

I have Flutter Firebase auth configured and it is working perfectly with Android.  But with ios, I cannot seem to get it to work.

Am using Xcode and Flutter on MacOS deploying to a physical iphone()14.4) and I have followed the instructions:

1. Added googleservice-info.plist into project via Xcode.
2. Under Signing and capabilities in Xcode, Provisioning profile, Team , Bundle identifier, Signing certificate(Apple Development certificate) configured with no errors.  Push Notifications(Release) also enabled.
3. In developer.apple.com, under Identities->myapp, I have enabled Push Notifications.  I have also created development and production SSL certs inside Push Notifications.  Also created key for Apple Push Notifications service (APNs).
4. In my Firebase project, I have added iOS apps and all the fields are populated.  Under Cloud Messaging, in iOS apps, I have uploaded the APN key and both development and Production certs I got from Apple Developer.

I run 'flutter run --release' (I am using a physical iphone(14.4)) because debug mode is not allowed on 14.4.  App installs successfully.  I am able to navigate pages and even register email/pw with Firebase.  But when I do a Firebase phone auth (verifyPhoneNumber), I keep getting an error as indicated by a snackbar error I coded in.  Problem is that I cannot get the specific error from the logs since I have deployed using release and flutter logs remain blank.

I don't know what else to do.  Please help.

Comment: Can't you display the error in the snackbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Problem was with URL Types under Info of target Runner.  Had to add URL Scheme.  For those who has this problem, refer to the below.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

iOS uses captcha with Firebase.